# retrying something 3 times before throwing an exception - in clojure

Tags: clojure

I don't know how to implement this piece of Python code in Clojure

```
for i in range(3):
    try:
        ......
    except e:
        if i == 2:
            raise e
        else:
            continue
    else:
        break
```

I wonder why something so simple in Python is so hard in Clojure. I think the difficulty is because Clojure is a functional programming language and thus is not suitable for such an imperative task. This is my attempt:

```
(first
  (remove #(instance? Exception %)
    (for [i (range 3)]
      (try (......)
              (catch Exception e
                (if (== i 2) 
                  (throw e)
                  e)))))))
```

It is very ugly, and worse, it doesn't work as expected. The for loop is actually evaluated fully instead of lazily (I realized this when I put a println inside).

If anyone has a better idea to implement that, please enlighten me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clojure: How to to recur upon exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879885/clojure-how-to-to-recur-upon-exception)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Similar to Marcyk's answer, but no macro trickery:

```
(defn retry
  [retries f & args]
  (let [res (try {:value (apply f args)}
                 (catch Exception e
                   (if (zero? retries)
                     (throw e)
                     {:exception e})))]
    (if (:exception res)
      (recur (dec retries) f args)
      (:value res))))
```

Slightly complicated because you can't `recur` inside a `catch` clause. Note that this takes a function:

```
(retry 3 (fn [] 
          (println "foo") 
          (if (zero? (rand-int 2))
              (throw (Exception. "foo"))
              2)))
=>
foo ;; one or two or three of these
foo
2
```

Comment: A minor point nitpick about the comment in the example -- as written, this will print up to four `foo`s, not three, when passed an inital argument of 3. (`f` is applied to `args` before the zero check.)

Comment: You could call yourself from inside a catch though (no stack overflow for small values of *tries*). But I like your solution.

Comment: Yeah that should be up to four - tries should probably be called *re*tries in this instance.

Comment: If you want tries to represent the max number of attempts replace `(= 0 tries)` by `(= 1 tries)`.

Comment: both are excellent solutions, but I prefer one without macro, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Here's one approach:

```
(defmacro retry
  "Evaluates expr up to cnt + 1 times, retrying if an exception
  is thrown. If an exception is thrown on the final attempt, it
  is allowed to bubble up."
  [cnt expr]
  (letfn [(go [cnt]
            (if (zero? cnt)
              expr
              `(try ~expr
                    (catch Exception e#
                      (retry ~(dec cnt) ~expr)))))]
    (go cnt)))
```

Example from the REPL:

```
user> (retry 2 (do (println :foo) (throw (RuntimeException. "foo"))))
:foo
:foo
:foo
; Evaluation aborted.
```

(Passing `2` to `retry` asks `expr` to be retried twice it if fails the first time round, for a total of three attempts. Three `:foo`s are printed, because the `println` occurs before the `throw` in the `do` form passed to `retry`. The final `; Evaluation aborted.` means an exception was thrown.)

Also, about the `for` loop from your snippet:

If you try looping over a longer range (replace `(range 3)` with `(range 10)`, say), the output will end after `i` reaches `3`. Also, if you put in a `println` before the form which throws the exception, it will of course print out whatever you pass to it; if the `println` occurs after the exception-throwing form, there will be no printout. In any case, at most three calls to `println` will be executed (assuming an exception is thrown on every iteration).

Answer (score 0):

```
(cond (every? nil? (for [x (range (inc retry)) :while (not @tmp-doc)]
 ...do sth) )                  
;all failed
:else
;at least one success
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
(defn retry
  "Tries at most n times, return first try satisfying pred or nil"
  [times pred? lazy-seq]
  (let [successful-trial (drop-while (complement pred?) (take times lazy-seq))]
    (if (empty? successful-trial)
        nil
        (first successful-trial))))
```

Then you could use the function as such:

```
(when-not (retry 3 pos? (repeatedly #(rand-nth [-1 -2 -3 2 1]))
    (throw (Exception. "my exception message"))
```

This would try at most three times to take a positive number at random from the vector and if it doesn't succeed, throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Retry with sleep and another implementation based on this question's answers:

```
(defn retry [retries sleep-ms func url options]
  (let [{:keys [status headers body error] :as resp} @(func url options)]
    (if error
      (do
        (log/error (str "Retry " retries " returned error: " e))
        (Thread/sleep sleep-ms)
        (if (= retries 1)
          resp
          (retry (dec retries) sleep-ms func url options)))
      resp)))
```