# Mock API call failure and test Retry in Clojure

Tags: clojure, mocking

I have a set function that calls an API of another Service.

I implemented a feature where

1. I retry the set() upto 3 times if the set() fails.
2. If retry() fails for all the 3 times, cut a ticket (generate an email saying there is an error in set() ).

I want to test the above feature.

1. Mock the set() such that I can verify retry works
   successfully.
2. Mock set() and retry such that   I can verify
   the creation of ticket.

How can I mock the above scenarios in clojure?

My function looks like this:

```
(defn set *
  "Set"
  [param1 param2 param3]
  (try
    (utils/retry 2
                 (do (set param1 param2 param3)))
    (catch Exception e
      (cut-ticket))))




(defmacro retry
  "Evaluates expr up to cnt + 1 times, retrying if an exception
  is thrown. If an exception is thrown on the final attempt, it
  is allowed to bubble up."
  [cnt expr]
  (letfn [(go [cnt]
            (if (zero? cnt)
              expr
              `(try ~expr
                    (catch Exception e#
                      (retry ~(dec cnt) ~expr)))))]
    (go cnt)))
```

Ref: [retrying something 3 times before throwing an exception - in clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068640/retrying-something-3-times-before-throwing-an-exception-in-clojure)

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading about `with-redefs`:    https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-redefs

This should solve question #1.  I'm not sure you need to mock `retry`, just create a mock for `cut-ticket`

Comment: Thanks. cut-ticket creates a ticket, as in, it generates an email saying there is a problem. I want to verify that the email was generated. So I don't need to create a mock for cut-ticket. My goal is to test if I am successfully cutting the ticket (generating the email) or not. I hope that clarifies the 2nd question.