# Why recur from catch section in Clojure is illegal

Tags: clojure

There already at least [one answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879885/clojure-how-to-to-recur-upon-exception) regarding recur on exception. My question is why this `recur` is not accepted by Clojure compiler

```
(loop []
  (try
    (catch Exception _ex
      (recur))))
```

with error "Can only recur from tail position".

According to control flow this `recur` *is* in tail position since code does nothing after `recur` inside `loop` form.

Comment: Apparently `recur` is not allowed in the `finally` clause either. `(loop [] (try (catch Exception _) (finally (recur))))` causes the same compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

If in asking "Why is this so?", you are asking for the history, you may get a better answer posting this question to the Clojure mailing list at `clojure@googlegroups.com`.  I suspect the reason is that the the compiler authors never considered this use-case.

You can simulate your desired behavior easily enough as this example shows. It does not use macros like most of the answers from the previous question linked:

```
    (loop [count 5]
      (newline)
      (println "top of loop; count=" count)
      (let [caught-ex (try
                        (println "in try")
                        (/ 1 0)
                        false
                        (catch Exception ex
                          (println "   in catch; count=" count "   cause:  " (.getMessage ex))
                          true))]
           (when (and caught-ex
                   (pos? count))
             (recur (dec count)))))
```

with result:

```
top of loop; count= 5
in try
   in catch; count= 5    cause:   Divide by zero

top of loop; count= 4
in try
   in catch; count= 4    cause:   Divide by zero

top of loop; count= 3
in try
   in catch; count= 3    cause:   Divide by zero

top of loop; count= 2
in try
   in catch; count= 2    cause:   Divide by zero

top of loop; count= 1
in try
   in catch; count= 1    cause:   Divide by zero

top of loop; count= 0
in try
   in catch; count= 0    cause:   Divide by zero
```

Comment: This use case was certainly considered, and has been discussed before. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/0A32oPAyeoY and https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-31?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Achangehistory-tabpanel#issue-tabs for example.